# ScrollView not scrolling which has ListView inside (listview is scrolling)

Tags: android, listview, android-scrollview

I have a ListView inside ScrollView, the ListView works fine (it scrolls) but the ScrollView is not scrolling

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

            <ListView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

I want the full page to scroll (The textview should also scroll)

```
TextView
ListView
 item1
 item2
 .
 .
```

The full page must scroll along with the textview!

Comment: Becuase it make no sens(putting scrollable into scrollable) ... It is a common problem did you read something about it?

Comment: @Selvin yes i do know its not a standard way to put scrollable inside scrollable but, i dont know a way around ! I did read some problems but all I could find is the ListView not working inside the Scrollview but for me, the ScrollView not working and the ListView does work!

Comment: Obviously becuase the second LinearLayout will take space up to outer(first) LinearLayout and THERE IS NOTHING TO SCROLL in ScrollView (as all: 1st LinearLayout, ScrollView and 2nd LinearLayout would have the same height)

Comment: Exactly Selvin, he needs to remove the first LinearLayout, but it would still be poor design because if you tried scrolling the full page but hit the list instead it would scroll the list until it had finished. if he had some more Textviews under the list then it would continue to scroll once the list had scrolled

Comment: @Rob85- I do have a layout included in between 1st LinearLayout and the ScrollView                                                                                    `LinearLayout 
 <include layout="@layout/custom_simple_toolbar" />
ScrollView`

Answer (score 1):

This will never work because your listView is effectively a scrollView, so you have a scrollView within a scrollView. Is the textView of fixed size or can it be a large amount of text? I would consider some redesign here as this is not a very good way to design a UI.

If the textView is big which means you only see a small bit of the list then you should be able to scroll by touching the textView only, but i would make the scrollView the Parent and remove the first LinearLayout, it is not needed

Comment: i have a include layout in between the linearlayout and scrollview     <include layout="@layout/custom_simple_toolbar" />

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ListView switch to RecyclerView and inside your **MainActivity.java** in **onCreate()** do this 
`recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 0):

You should never use a ScrollView with a ListView, because ListView takes care of its own vertical scrolling. Most importantly, doing this defeats all of the important optimizations in ListView for dealing with large lists, since it effectively forces the ListView to display its entire list of items to fill up the infinite container supplied by ScrollView.

The TextView class also takes care of its own scrolling, so does not require a ScrollView, but using the two together is possible to achieve the effect of a text view within a larger container.